# How to efficiently aggregate by segments in Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, concatenation, pandas-groupby

I'm looking to find an alternate way to group "total" groupings. Below is over simplified example of what I'm currently doing to create a total grouping. Currently, I'm creating a separate "total" data frame and merging it with the original one. Is there a better way to approach this problem?

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'new_ren':['new', 'ren', 'new', 'new', 'ren'],
                   'dt':['2022-01-01', '2022-01-01', '2022-02-01', '2022-02-01', '2022-03-01'],
                   'ct':[1, 3, 4, 1, 2]})

# create total grouping
df_tot = df.groupby('dt')['ct'].sum().reset_index()
df_tot['new_ren'] = 'total'

# combined both dataframes
pd.concat([df, df_tot])
```

Comment: If you set an index in your original df, you can group by those indicies and align automatically. But that doesn't seem to be what your code intends to do. The way you have it set up, I think this is the only way to do it.

Comment: what if you have multiple different dates? please edit your question if so

Comment: @anky I updated my example, but in this case I would like to keep dates as part of my grouping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with your approach (I'd say, it's the most intuitive and readable for your current problem) but here's an alternative way using `merge` to get the same output:

```
out = df.merge(df.groupby('dt', as_index=False).sum('ct').assign(new_ren='total'), how='outer')
```

Output:

```
  new_ren          dt  ct
0     new  2022-01-01   1
1     ren  2022-01-01   3
2     new  2022-02-01   4
3     new  2022-02-01   1
4     ren  2022-03-01   2
5   total  2022-01-01   4
6   total  2022-02-01   5
7   total  2022-03-01   2
```